# How should I obtain high accuracy using expo location?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, location

I am using `expo-location` from [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationobjectcoords) As per all the examples I read the following code should do the trick:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
      });
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);
```

However, the location which is being fetched is really really not high. When I print it on the console I got:

```
location:  Object {
  "coords": Object {
    "accuracy": 41.36199951171875,
    "altitude": some altitude,
    "altitudeAccuracy": 41.362125396728516,
    "heading": 230,
    "latitude": not important,
    "longitude": not important,
    "speed": I dont know what is this for,
  },
  "mocked": false,
  "timestamp": not important,
}
```

As you can see `location.coords.accuracy` is quite high. As far as I understand, in order to get closer to my actual location I should make this number smaller.

What I notice is that if I refresh the page several times, my location is more accurate. So I wrote the following "improvement":

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [calculateLocationAgain, setCalculateLocationAgain] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
      });
      setLocation(location);
      isAccuracyTooHigh(location);
    })();
  }, [calculateLocationAgain]);

function isAccuracyTooHigh(location) {
    if (!location) {
      setCalculateLocationAgain(!calculateLocationAgain);
    } else if (location.coords.accuracy > 10) {
      setCalculateLocationAgain(!calculateLocationAgain);
    }
  }
```

Basically, I say "keep fetching the location, until location.coords.accuracy <= 10". Which indeed, does work, it gives me high and precise location this time.

What is not cool about this solution is that I keep refreshing the page something like 40 times, which I find it unnecessary.

For sure, there must be some reason, why my location is not being fetched with high precision on the first place. I could not find any similar problems, or questions.

I am testing on Android, if that matters.